# Set of first order differential equations for arbitrary coefficients matrix.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose one has a set of coupled differential equations in the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f_{i}(x)}{dx} = a_{ij}(x)f_{i}(x)\left(1 - \frac{1}{f_{i}(x)g_{j}(x)}\right)\nonumber\\
\frac{g_{i}(x)}{dx} = a_{ij}(x)g_{i}(x)\left(1 - \frac{1}{g_{i}(x)f_{j}(x)}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
for $i,j\in\{1,2,...,N\}$, and arbitrary matrix $a_{ij}(x)$ $\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way  to work out closed form expressions for this system of $N^{2}$ coupled ODEs?

Comment: Is there a sum missing in the ODE, or are you assuming the summation convention? If not, how is $j$ selected, there can be only one equation for each $i$. Also, in this second case, the equations are not coupled, the equation for $f_i$ only depends on $f_i$.

Comment: No, $\dot y(x)=A(x)y(x)$ does not have, in general, a solution formula that is based on the exponential or matrix exponential. See fundamental matrix, propagator (semi-)group, etc.

Comment: There is no summation in $j$ in the first expression, so indeed there are $N^{2}$ equations; I will reformulate the question with a case for $N^{2}$ unknowns.

Comment: That does not make any sense, the derivative can only be one number, not $N$ numbers at the same time. Is there a deeper motivation for the system, is it derived from some "first principles"?

Comment: The system results from requiring two sides to equal each other in an equation of the form $\int dx F_{ij}(x) = \int dx G_{ij}(x)$, with $F_{ij}(x)$ and $G_{ij}(x)$ some complicated structures in terms of the $g,f,a$, which also contains the derivative of these functions.

Comment: For instance we can have $F_{ij}(x)\propto f_{i}(x)\frac{d g{j}(x)}{dx} + f_{i}(x)a_{ij}(x)g_{j}(x)$ on the LHS integrand.

Comment: How do you get locality? Is there some variational principle involved? Usually the identity of the integrals does not imply the identity of the integrands.

Comment: Using the identity of the integrands is a more restrictive way to make the equation to be satisfied, I agree on that. But isn't one allowed to do that in general?

Comment: Not as a conclusion, a necessary condition. It may be sufficient if it does not lead to contradictions.

Comment: So summarizing, the above identification of the integrands leads to an inconsistency in so that there are N different values for a single derivative $df_{i}(x)/dx$, and thus the identity cannot be proved by this set of ODEs, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You are putting too many constraints on the integrands so that the admissible set becomes empty.

Comment: What is then the course of action to determine the functions $F_{ij}(x)$ that satisfy the identity $\int dx F_{ij}(x) = \int dx G_{ij}(x)$? Considering $F_{ij}$  can depend on the product $f_{i}(x)g_{j}(x)$ and $f_{i}(x)d g_{j}(x)/dx$, but with complete knowledge of the RHS $G_{ij}(x)$ terms? It seems to me this is a non-trivial inversion problem then.

Comment: Is that integral identity in the sense of anti-derivative functions, or over a fixed domain? In the first case I have to take back my earlier refutations a bit. Still, that means that you get $N$ ODE and $N^2-N$ algebraic equations that will be mostly conditions on the $a_{ij}$.

Comment: The integrals are defined over a finite domain $[0,A]$.